# SharePoint List dropdown/choice (colours)

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, choicefield

I would like to know if its possible to have a drop down field/column in SharePoint list that instead of having text choices to select from, the choices are graphics/images (green, red, amber). Or how about having a three divs as choices and each div will have the desired color.

Is any of this possible?

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant provide color coding to the choice filed directly

but there is one way to do something similar to this.

please look at this link

http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2008/11/02/Adding-Color-Columns-to-Sharepoint-lists.aspx

In this it will get the color by using calculated field value. you can customize this as per your requirement

Let me the outcome as i m also eager to know this
Thanks